# dart-sass in Web Worker: `Error: Illegal invocation`

Tags: javascript, sass, web-worker

Running dart-sass in the browser isn't officially supported (#25), but maybe there's who someone can give me hints on how to debug this (very hard without source maps for the Dart code).

```
Error: Error: Illegal invocation
    at Object.AU (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:536605:15)
    at w6.$2 (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:556087:53)
    at u6.v7 (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:543941:33)
    at u6.v6 (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:543945:19)
    at ik.uh (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:542621:20)
    at tF.$0 (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:542922:19)
    at Object.ex (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:529758:55)
    at aj.bb (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:542753:9)
    at iz.bb (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:542606:14)
    at iz.cA (http://localhost:5000/ParcelWorker.cc8dae65.js:542577:12)
```

This happens when any importer (even a "noop" importer) is added. Executing this code on the main thread (using just `require`) works fine. The error is thrown without the importer being executed once.

```js
/*  index.js */

// this works:
require("./worker.js");

// this doesn't:
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");
worker.onerror = console.error;
```

```js
/*  worker.js */
self.Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;

const sass = require("sass");

const data = `$colorRed: red;
#header {
  color: $colorRed;
}`;

function run() {
    return sass.renderSync({
        data,
        importer: [
            (url, prev, done) => {
                return { file: url };
            }
        ]
    });
}

console.log(run().css.toString("utf8"));
```

Complete reproduction (just run `npm i` and `npm start`): https://github.com/mischnic/sass-worker-importer - the error is printed to the console

Comment: `const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");` isn't valid in any setup I've seen.

`import Worker from "./worker.js"; const worker = new Worker()` would be my assumption

Comment: @StevenStark That's the only way to create a worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Spawning_a_dedicated_worker ---
`import Worker from ...` doesn't actually create a worker, it just imports that module.

Comment: I put two statements on one line there. first import, second instantiate.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But that syntax won't work in a browser. What is `Worker` really in that case? The standardized `Worker` constructor takes a URL.

Comment: I think you're confused. require is used to import a .js file in the old days, and since has been migrated to import syntax. 

Worker is a native API that instantiates a new worker and defines the worker by referencing a .js file. This is not an import, as it already exists in the browser. `require('./worker.js')` will compile, but it will not create a new Worker instance.

I suspect your `worker.js` might not be found, is it hosted at the same level as your page?

Sorry for the initial confusion, I thought you were trying to import a custom worker lib.

Comment: In the repository I provided, I've setup [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to bundle that file (because I can't just import sass in the browser). I think were talking about the webpack's worker-loader specific syntax. --- Anyway, the Worker part is working fine, this is just about the `importer` option (if I remove that part, everything works as expected).

Comment: you don't import or require Worker, you just instantiate it. it's a type like string, boolean, Object, etc.

Comment: Yes, you instantiate it by passing it a url to the code to execute. `require('./worker.js')` does indeed not create a Worker, this line demonstrates the `Executing this code on the main thread work`-part of the my question.

Comment: `require('./worker.js')` is just wrong though, do not do this.

Comment: How is it "wrong"? It _will_ execute the code in `worker.js`, it's rather "deceiving" given how that file is called.

Comment: it's wrong because you're misusing require.

This might appear to be working, but it will not work at all without webpack. you will be unable to ever deliver this to an actual server.

worker.js needs to be hosted, and you create a new worker by providing a string to the hosted worker.js file. 

Require / import is for including code during your compilation steps. 

The concepts are unrelated. It's only by chance that this even works at all in webpack dev server

Comment: This doesn't work in webpack. The bundler I'm using will transparently take the first argument of the Worker constructor as an entrypoint for a new JS bundle. And again, `require("./worker.js");` is for the "works on the main thread" argument. --- Or is this really about how `require` and `new Worker` are both called? The snippet I posted in the question is really meant like: "this first version works (require)" and "this second version doesn't (Worker)"

Comment: Ok, let's try again. Web workers take a single js file, uploads that file to the clients device, and then executes the code entirely outside of the Dom. This means that it is not part of your bundle. It's an asset all on it's own, like an image is.

Comment: Yes. So I have two cases: 1. load sass in "normal" JS/DOM environment. That works. 2. The DOM env creates a worker, that loads the worker bundle with the sass import. Now I get this cryptic error (in the worker).

Comment: there is no DOM with web workers, meaning trying to import a css pre processor will likely cause weird and strange errors; it's nonsensical. There is no DOM so there is no css. Furthermore, you would never import this anyhow. it's a pre-processor, to be used at build time not run time.

Comment: I don't need a DOM, I just want to compile the sass I pass to `dart-sass` (this works in Node as well - without a DOM, it even works fine in the browser without the `importer` option set to some value). The reason for this question is that I'm "porting" a bundler to the browser (for debugging purposes and to help with GitHub issues): https://parcel-repl.now.sh/ (so the worker is the "build time").

Comment: a web worker is NOT node and does NOT have the ability to do what you're trying. think simpler. their job is to do processing, like math functions. this is far outside their scope.